# Multi-dependency makefile target

Tags: makefile, dockerfile

The problem I'm experiencing is an `all` target has dependencies on others that set a variable, then run matching dependencies.

**Outcome** - It will run the first dependency then stop.

**Expected** - Run both dependencies, setting the variable properly between each run

Is `make` smart enough to see `pull` and `build` were already ran and the dependency target itself has no execution, therefore it sees all dependencies as complete? Or I'm just abusing `make` in ways it should not be used?

Said `makefile`:

```
repo=rippio
image=default

pull:
    @docker pull $(repo)/$(image):latest

build: pull
    @sed -e 's/{{repo}}/$(repo)/' -e 's/{{image}}/$(image)/' Dockerfile.in > Dockerfile && \
    docker build -t=$(repo)/$(image):custom .
    @rm -f Dockerfile

node: image=node
node: | pull build

jdk8: image=jdk8
jdk8: | pull build

all: | node jdk8
```

---

### TLDR

It is used to:

1. Pull the latest docker image
2. Run a generically designed Dockerfile against it to customize it
3. Tag it as :custom for internal use

Pretty handy for customizing images in a generic manner without managing many `Dockerfiles`.

Dockerfile template (`Dockerfile.in`), incase interested:

```
FROM {{repo}}/{{image}}:latest

... super secret sauce
```

---

### UPDATE (ANSWER)

Thanks to [@G.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371123/g-m), ended up with:

```
IMAGE_NAMES := node jdk8
TARGETS     := $(patsubst %,build-%,$(IMAGE_NAMES))

repo=rippio

all: $(TARGETS)

build-%: pull-%
        @$sed -e 's/{{repo}}/$(repo)/' -e 's/{{image}}/$*/' Dockerfile.in > Dockerfile-$* && \
        $docker build -f=Dockerfile-$* -t=$(repo)/$*:custom .
        @rm -f Dockerfile-$*

pull-%:
        @$docker pull $(repo)/$*:latest
```

Which allows for:

- Easy upkeep of 'all' targets, which constantly grows
- Running parallel via `make -j` (note the `Dockerfile-$*` file pattern)
- Much more beautiful than before

Comment: Is this a Make or CMake question?

Comment: Whoops! Brain fart -- It's a `Make` question -- corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw your dependency graph out long-hand you'll see that there are multiple paths from `all` to both `pull` and `build` -- one via each of `node` and `jdk8`.  But `make` having reached/updated `pull` and `build` via one path will then assume that they are both up to date and, hence, not bother to update them further -- regardless of any change to target specific variables.

I think what you're trying to do (assuming I've understood correctly) might be more easily achieved using pattern rules.

```
IMAGE_NAMES := node jdk8
TARGETS     := $(patsubst %,build-%,$(IMAGE_NAMES))

repo=rippio

all: $(TARGETS)

build-%: pull-%
        @$sed -e 's/{{repo}}/$(repo)/' -e 's/{{image}}/$*/' Dockerfile.in > Dockerfile && \
        $docker build -t=$(repo)/$*:custom .
        @rm -f Dockerfile

pull-%:
        @$docker pull $(repo)/$*:latest
```

**Note:**  You currently have all `build` recipes using the same input/output file `DockerFile`.  That will cause problems if you ever want to use parallel builds -- `make -j` etc.  It might be wise to use the stem from the pattern rule match to uniquely identify the output file if that's possible.

Comment: Awesome! This layout makes it really easy to maintain the image list for `all` as well. I didn't realize you could use the pattern match in this way and never knew about `make -j`. Updating question with what I ended up with for running parallel!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you invoke make with:

```
make all
```

and if none of `pull`, `build`, `node`, `jdk8` are existing files, make should build `pull` and `build`. If you see only `pull` being made, it can be because you invoke make without specifying a goal. In this case make builds the first target it finds in the Makefile (`pull` in your case).

Anyway, there are several strange aspects in your Makefile: you use order-only prerequisites on what looks like phony targets and these phony targets are not declared as such.

I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do but maybe something like this would be a good starting point:

```
repo=rippio
image=default

.PHONY: all build node jdk8

all: node jdk8

node: image = node
jdk8: image = jdk8

build node jdk8:
    @docker pull $(repo)/$(image):latest && \
    sed -e 's/{{repo}}/$(repo)/' -e 's/{{image}}/$(image)/' Dockerfile.in > Dockerfile && \
    docker build -t=$(repo)/$(image):custom . && \
    rm -f Dockerfile
```

Note: if, instead of `build` you name the default target `default` you could even simplify further with:

```
repo=rippio

.PHONY: all default node jdk8

all: node jdk8

default node jdk8:
    @docker pull $(repo)/$@:latest && \
    sed -e 's/{{repo}}/$(repo)/' -e 's/{{image}}/$@/' Dockerfile.in > Dockerfile && \
    docker build -t=$(repo)/$@:custom . && \
    rm -f Dockerfile
```

Comment: Apologies - it was a simplified version of the makefile and I left off the `.PHONY` - all targets are non-representative of a file. It templates out a Dockerfile in order to run `docker build` to pull and produce a container within docker, then delete the dockerfile.
Your suggestion helped - I forgot about the `$@`, which does simplify this process, but I have to give it to @g-m for the pattern solution which fits perfectly

Comment: @Charly: no problem, I also use patterns a lot and I find @-m solution very nice and elegant.